# How can I efficiently dereference all symlinks in `find` *output* filenames?

Tags: linux, find, symlink

I need paths to be both fully resolved and relative to a given directory. This must be done efficiently, since the number of paths is often greater than 100,000.

**Situation**: I have directories which contain *mostly* symlinks to other directories, as in

```
foo
 123 -> ../baz/123
 896 -> ../bar/896
```

(Note that foo does NOT contain only symlinks to directories, it also contains ordinary files which I have to catch too.)

These symlinked directories contain files. . I want to get a list of those files, in the form

```
baz/123/some.file
bar/123/other.file
```

That is, when 'find' finds a symlink, I want it to dereference that path **when it is reporting the contents**.

So I am running this command from the parent directory of foo:

```
find -L foo -type f
```

But that doesn't work.

Honestly, you would expect the `-L` option, which claims to 'follow symbolic links', to implement this behaviour. But, its **actual** behaviour is to look *into* the contents of those directories, but report files inside them with their non-dereferenced names, ie. the results look like

```
foo/baz/123/some.file
foo/bar/896/another.file
```

The results will be used for set operations against a list of filepaths that are all 1. *fully resolved* and 2. *relative to foo's parent directory*, so every result must also fulfil that criteria. I can guarantee for these purposes that all links are resolvable ie. none are circular or excessively deep. Most, but not all links, point at directories rather than files.

At the moment, the best I can do is a Python script that rewrites any non-dereferenced paths into resolved ones. But since the numbers of files involved is in the **100000+** range, this is not very practical (and rather ridiculous, since `find` already had bothered to dereference them, it just didn't return the dereferenced paths).
(EDIT: See my comment on this post -- I've found a non-solution (in that it does the job efficiently but in the wrong way -- executing external commands).)

I'm convinced that I should be able to do this task just with `find` and no external commands, but I'm not finding the man page enlightening here -- none of `-L`, `-H`, `-P`, `-follow` have the correct behaviour, nor does `-printf %l`. `-exec` is out for obvious reasons -- it is not internal to `find`. Any ideas?

EDIT 2: at this point, Stephane has convinced me that there is no particularly good reason why find **would** have this functionality internally, so I'm willing to accept any reasonably efficient answer.

Comment: Right now I am using `find -L foo -type f -exec realpath {} "+" | sed "s,^$REALPATH_OF_TOPLEVEL_DIR,," `. This is actually acceptable in speed (3.8s to process 160000 files), but does not match the criteria of the question. I still believe that there is a way to do this basic thing without resorting to `-exec`.

Comment: A variant of the above avoids the non-POSIX `-exec ... +` form: `find -L foo -type f -print0 | xargs -0 realpath --relative-to "$REALPATH_OF_TOPLEVEL_DIR"`. This is virtually identical to the non-posix `find -L foo -type f -exec realpath --relative-to "$REALPATH_OF_TOPLEVEL_DIR" {} "+"` except an extra process is spawned.

Comment: `find` doesn't dereference them, it just follows them, or ommits to ignore them when descending the directory tree if you prefer.

Comment: `-exec cmd {} +` is POSIX `-print0` and `realpath` are not.

Comment: @StephaneChazelas: Thanks for pointing that out, I think I picked up that misinformation elsewhere on StackOverflow. POSIX find standard doesn't have -print0, though? WHAT GOOD IS IT THEN ;) j/k.

Comment: A portable solution that is not impractically slow could probably be implemented using Python, as in `find -L foo -type f | python3 -c "import sys, os; realpath=os.path.realpath; for line in sys.stdin:\\n    print(realpath(line.rstrip()))\\n"` (where \\n should be actual newlines.). The relativization (for the simple case) could be easily added to that.

Comment: POSIX has `-printf '%s\0' {} +`. The problem is more than its `xargs` is unusable (no `-0`, no `-r`, and the minimum guaranteed limits are too low to be useful).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

What you're asking for doesn't make much sense in the general case, so it's not surprising that `find` has no provision for it.

A symlink with a relative target is relative to the path of the symlink. So for instance, if by traversing a directory by following symlinks, `find` encounters `a/b/c/d` and `a`, `a/b`, `a/b/c` are all relative or absolute symlinks (or symlinks to paths with symlink components), what should it do?

If you're looking for a `find` predicate or a GNU `-printf` `%` directive that expands to *a symlink-free path to the file relative to the current directory or any directory*, I'm afraid there's none.

If you're on Linux, you can get the absolute path of those files with:

```
find -L foo -type f -exec readlink -f {} \;
```

As you found out, there exists at least one `realpath` command which accepts more than one path argument which in combination with the standard `-exec cmd {} +` syntax is going to be a lot more efficient since it's running as few realpath commands as necessary:

```
find -L foo -type f -exec realpath {} +

find -L foo -type f -print0 | xargs -r0 realpath
```

might be quicker as if more than one `realpath` command is needed, `find` can keep on looking for more files while the first `realpath` starts working which even on a single processor system might make it more efficient.

`-print0` and `xargs -r0` are not standard, come from GNU but are found in a number of other implementations like most modern BSDs.

Zsh has builtin support for it:

```
print -rl foo/***/*(-.:A)
```

If you don't care about the sorting order, you can  disable sorting and make it a bit more efficient with:

```
print -rl foo/***/*(-.oN:A)
```

If you want to convert those to relative paths to the current directory, you could have a look at [that SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2564634/1627296).

If you know that all those files have an absolute canonical path (whose none of the components are symlinks) inside the current directory, you can simplify it to (still with `zsh`):

```
files=(foo/***/*(-.:A))
print -rl -- ${files#$PWD/}
```

Though short and convenient, and works whatever character filenames contain, I doubt it would faster than `find` + `realpath`.

With the Debian `realpath` and GNU tools, you can do:

```
cd -P .
find -L foo -type f -exec realpath -z {} + | 
  gawk -v p="$PWD" -v l="${#PWD}" -v RS='\0' -vORS='\0' '
    substr($0, 1, l+1) == p "/" {$0 = substr($0, l+2)}; 1' |
  xargs -r0 whatever you want to do with them
```

As I realise now, there's now a `realpath` in recent versions of GNU coreutils, which has the exact feature you're looking for, so it's just a matter of

```
find -L foo -type f -print0 |
  xargs -r0 realpath -z --relative-base . |
  xargs -r0 whatever you want to do with them
```

(use `--relative-to .` instead of `--relative-base .` if you want relative paths even for files whose symlink free path doesn't reside below the current working directory).

Comment: This is similar to what I had commented I was currently using (`find -L foo -type f -exec realpath {} "+" | sed "s,^$REALPATH_OF_TOPLEVEL_DIR,,"`. I still believe that I must be missing something, because this (choosing between resolved and unresolved output paths) seems like basic enough functionality that it would be included in `find` itself. BTW, the ";" form of exec, though it's the only POSIX-specified form, is far too slow when you are dealing with 100000+ files. The "+" form is faster but nonstandard. xargs is also a possibility if portability is really needed (it isn't in my case)

Comment: @kampu, `-exec cmd {} +` is POSIX and standard. But `readlink` accepts only one path argument. `readlink` comes as standard on most Linux systems since it's part of GNU coreutils. `realpath` not necessarily. Note that I hadn't seen your comment when replying.

Comment: Re: your edit: *A*) Is the a/b/c/d situation a problem? Find normally (by definition, of how you invoke it) returns paths relative to the current working directory, so any dereferencing of non-circular symlinks is unambiguous (even if said references happen to fall outside of $PWD).; *B*) I'm fascinated to see that the `print` command doesn't immediately fail with 'commandline too long' error. Instead it wanders off into the depths of my CPU for 5 minutes and then finally returns; C) `-exec readlink -f {} ;` is portable but horrendously inefficient (>200x slower than `realpath {} +`) ..

Comment: .. Well, in summary, I appreciate your effort to address this, and I want to accept this answer, I just can't reconcile this with the inefficiency of the proposed solutions. \*uncertain face\*

Comment: Or to put it more positively, I'm happy to accept your answer IFF it contains at least one answer that completes in reasonable time (less than a minute for < 200,000 files, a constraint which my current solution goes well past satisfying.)

Comment: @kampu, I doubt you can get faster than your current solution short of implementing it in C. You can post it as an answer and accept it.

Comment: @kampu, OK sorry, I realise now that `realpath` has also been added to the GNU coreutils (8.15) which explains your `--relative-to` option which I thought you used as options _you wished_ existed.

Comment: Wow, amazing update! I will definitely accept this, it's a very thorough treatment of the subject. I do want to mention to you that the `print -rl foo/***/*(-.:A)` command had a detrimental effect on the session of zsh it was running in -- after each command completed, it would take a long time (15s) to bring up it's prompt. Possibly a zsh bug (I'm running v5.0.2 FWIW) as that line doesn't seem that it would create any lurking junk, but something to be aware of nonetheless. I especially appreciate the note about `--relative-base` as that's indeed the behaviour I really want.

Comment: On reflection, I think that the `print` command caused zsh to expand some internal commandline-buffer to 8mb in size (this is a rough guess at how many characters are in the resolved `foo/***/*(-.:A)`, since there are around 160000 files, for which the path ranges between 40-60 chars each on average.) And it reinits this buffer before each prompt (which is unnoticable at normal size, but *very* noticable at 8mb). A reasonable workaround might be to run it in another zsh instance as in `zsh -c 'print -rl foo/***/*(-.:A)' > outputfile`. Or just use a different method entirely, of course :)

Answer (score 0):

ls -1 -R --dereference | wc -l

did the trick for me. But I only needed a count for the number of files, recursively tunneling into the destinations of any symbolic links. I did not need to display them. but since you do, just drop the pipe and word count, so simply as follows:

ls -1 -R --dereference